# Python print out float or integer

Tags: python, coding-style, string-formatting, if-statement

How can i print out float if the result have decimal or print out integer if the result have no decimal?

```
c = input("Enter the total cost of purchase: ")
bank = raw_input("Enter the bank of your credit card (DBS, OCBC, etc.): ")
dbs1 = ((c/float(100))*10)
dbs2 = c-dbs1
ocbc1 = ((c/float(100))*15)
ocbc2 = c-ocbc1


if (c > 200):
    if (bank == 'DBS'):
        print('Please pay $'+str(dbs2))
    elif (bank == 'OCBC'):
        print('Please pay $'+str(ocbc2))
    else:
        print('Please pay $'+str(c))
else:
    print('Please pay $'+str(c))

exit = raw_input("Enter to exit")
```

---

### Example-Result

```
Enter the total cost of purchase: 250
Enter the bank of your credit card (DBS, OCBC, etc.): OCBC
Please pay $212.5

Enter the total cost of purchase: 250
Enter the bank of your credit card (DBS, OCBC, etc.): DBS
Please pay $225.0
```

Comment: I dont see the problem i ran it and it worked fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this, which simply uses Python's string formatting method:

```
if int(c) == float(c):
    decimals = 0
else:
    decimals = 2 # Assumes 2 decimal places for money

print('Please pay: ${0:.{1}f}'.format(c, decimals))
```

This will give you the following output if `c == 1.00`:

```
Please pay: $1
```

Or this output if `c == 20.56`:

```
Please pay: $20.56
```

Answer (score 5):

Python floats have a built-in method to determine whether they're an integer:

```
x = 212.50
y = 212.0
f = lambda x: int(x) if x.is_integer() else x
print(x, f(x), y, f(y), sep='\t')
>> 212.5    212.5   212.0   212
```

Answer (score 5):

Since there is a much simpler way now and this post is the first result, people should know about it:

```
print(f"{3.0:g}")  # 3
print(f"{3.14:g}")  # 3.14
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def nice_print(i):
    print '%.2f' % i if i - int(i) != 0 else '%d' % i

nice_print(44)
44

nice_print(44.345)
44.34
```

in Your code:

```
def nice_number(i):
    return '%.2f' % i if i - int(i) != 0 else '%d' % i

c = input("Enter the total cost of purchase: ")
bank = raw_input("Enter the bank of your credit card (DBS, OCBC, etc.): ")
dbs1 = ((c/float(100))*10)
dbs2 = c-dbs1
ocbc1 = ((c/float(100))*15)
ocbc2 = c-ocbc1


if (c > 200):
    if (bank == 'DBS'):
        print('Please pay $'+nice_number(dbs2))
    elif (bank == 'OCBC'):
        print('Please pay $'+nice_number(ocbc2))
    else:
        print('Please pay $'+nice_number(c))
else:
    print('Please pay $'+nice_number(c))
```