# python built-in function for float to int in specific case

Tags: python, built-in

I have a function which return float value for example 4.0 or 4.8

I want if the function returns 4.0 then it should print 4 only but if it return any other value example- 4.1, 4.3, 4.8 then it should print as it is.

I know this can be done through conditions or by making custom functions but i wanted to know is there any builtin function in python by which i can do this.

Comment: Are you asking if there's a function to check for fractional part in a float?

Comment: yes something on fractional part if it is 4.0 then print 4 only if 4.8 then 4.8 only.

Comment: @Aran-Fey. Another approach: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21583758/2988730

Comment: As far as I know there is no builtin function for printing like this, however there is a builtin function to check whether a number is an integer, namely `float.is_integer()`, e.g. `(4.8).is_integer()` yields `False` and `(4.0).is_integer()` yields `True`

Comment: @ThijsvanEde yup https://stackoverflow.com/a/16577771/6451573

Comment: Neat. I didn't know you could edit the list of duplicates once the question is hammered.

Comment: You can try: `print(str(x).rstrip('.0')`