# How can I accept the user input in such a way that my program recognizes whether it is an int or a float?

Tags: python

can anyone show me how I can accept integer and float for my input (in the list)? Because if I enter numbers in full, the result always comes out with a .0

Here is my code:

```
user = int(input("How many numbers do you want to sum up: "))
list = [float(input("Number: ")) for i in range (user)]
print("The Sum of the entered Numbers is: ", sum(list))
```

my output would look like this:

```
How many numbers do you want to sum up: 3
Number: 2
Number: 1
Number: 5
The Sum of the entered Numbers is:  8.0
```

Comment: Please update your question with sample inputs and outputs.

Comment: Why did you use `float(input(...`? Why not `int(input(...`?

Comment: @quamrana because if i write floating point numbers i get an error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python print out float or integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577669/python-print-out-float-or-integer)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do:

```py
user = int(input("How many numbers do you want to sum up: "))
list = [float(input("Number: ")) for i in range (user)]
x = sum(list)
if x.is_integer():
    x = int(x)
print("The Sum of the entered Numbers is: ", x)
```